# Vuex: Child component wait for parent component dispatch action

Tags: vue.js, action, vuex, getter

**Parent component (Dashboard):**

```
<template>
<div id="dashboard">
  <Header />
  <b-container>
    <div>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <Overview />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/common/Header';
import Overview from '@/components/dashboard/Overview';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  components: {
    Header,
    Overview
  },
  mounted() {
    const sessionId = this.$cookie.get('connect.sid');
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getUser', sessionId).then((userData) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('project/getProject', userData.data.user);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('user', {
      user: 'getUser'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child component (Overview):**

```
<template>
<div class="overview">
  <div class="overview__title">
    <h1>
      Welcome {{user.cn[0]}} // Works
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="overview__project">
    <p v-for="project in runningprojects" :key="project._id">
      {{project.name}} // Does not work at refresh
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: 'dashboard-overview',
  data() {
    return {
      runningprojects: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('user', {
      user: 'getUser'
    }),
    ...mapGetters('project', {
      projects: 'getProjects',
      allProjects: 'getAllProjects'
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted this.projects", this.projects);
    // add something from this.projects to this.runningprojects
  },
  methods: {
    calcReq() {
      ...
    },
    ...
}
</script>
```

In my Dashboard component (parent) I fetch the user data with a vuex action `dispatch('user/getUser)` and after that I fetch the projects of this user `dispatch('project/getProject)`.

In my Overview component (child) I want to show the project information of this user. I call my `mapGetters` and I have a component variable `runningprojects` inside `data()`. In my `mounted()` lifecycle I want to push data from my getters to this data array.

**The following problem is given:**

When I refresh my application, the `console.log` from my child component `mounted()` is called before the dispatch jobs are finished in the parent component (dashboard).

It only works if change something in my local files and vue-cli does a live reload.

[image: chrome dev tools]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the page `lifecycle` of the vue app. when component renders `mounted` is called after `created` and it wont wait for the `ajax` or any `async` calls.

**One solution would be to not `render` the `child component` until the `async` return**

```
<template>
<div id="dashboard">
  <Header />
  <b-container>
    <div>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <Overview v-if="finished"/>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/common/Header';
import Overview from '@/components/dashboard/Overview';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data() {
    return {
      finished: false,
    }
  },
  components: {
    Header,
    Overview
  },
  mounted() {
    const sessionId = this.$cookie.get('connect.sid');
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getUser', sessionId).then((userData) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('project/getProject', userData.data.user);
      this.finished = true;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('user', {
      user: 'getUser'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Just add a `v-if` in the `child component` and when `dispatch` has return then set the value to `true` which will render the `child component` and the then the `mounted` will have the values you want

**Other solution would be.**

Use `updated` function instead of `mounted` and which will be called when ever there is a change in the state.